# Units conversion on a PIC 18F2431

Tags: optimization, floating-point, long-integer, pic

I have the following conversion given Pressure per Square Inch (PSI) and Megapascals (MPa):

```
psi = MPa*1.45038;
```

I need the lowest value possible after conversion to be 1 PSI.  An example of what I am looking for is:

```
psi = ((long)MPa*145)/100
```

Is there anyway to optimize this for memory and speed by not using `float` or `long`?  I will be implementing this conversion on a microcontroller (PIC 18F2431).

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values of `MPa`?

Comment: So `MPa` is in the range [0,20]?

Comment: The range of values 0~2000MPa.

Comment: Sorry it is 0~2000MPa [0,2000] not [0,20].

Comment: Well, then you can use `psi = (MPa*1520833)>>20` or `psi = ((unsigned)MPa*1520833)>>20` if `MPa` is not `unsigned`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should **divide by powers of 2** instead which is far cheaper than division by any other values. And if the type can't be negative then use an unsigned type instead. Depending on the type of `MPa` and its maximum value you can choose different denominator to suite your needs. No need to cast to a wider type if the multiplication won't overflow

For example if `MPa` is of type `uint16_t` you can do `psi = MPa*95052/(1UL << 16);` (95052/65536 ≈ 1.450378)

If MPa is not larger than 1024 or 2<sup>10</sup> then you can multiply it with 2<sup>21</sup> without overflowing, thus you can increase the numerator/denominator for more precision

```
psi = MPa*3041667/(1UL << 21);
```

---

## Edit:

On the PIC 18F2431 `int` is a 16-bit type. That means 95052 will be of type `long` and `MPa` will be promoted to `long` in the expression. If you don't need much precision then change the scaling to fit in an `int`/`int16_t` to avoid dealing with `long`

In case MPa is not larger than 20 you can divide it by 2048 which is the largest power of 2 that is less than or equal to 2<sup>16</sup>/20.

```
psi = MPa*2970/(1U << 11);
```

Note that the `*` and `/` have equal precedence so it'll be evaluated from left to right, and the above equation will be identical to

```
psi = (MPa*2970)/2048; // = MPa*1.4501953125)
```

no need for such excessive parentheses

---

## Edit 2:

Unfortunately if the range of `MPa` is [0, 2000] then you can only multiply it by 32 without overflowing a 16-bit unsigned int. The closest ratio that you can achieve is `46/32 = 1.4375` so if you need more precision, there's no way other than using `long`. Anyway integer math with `long` is still **a lot** faster than floating-point math on the PIC MCU, and cost significantly less code space

Comment: Please clarify 1)MPa*95092 will overflow a 16 bit integer.Otherwise 2)95052/65536 will give 1,not 1.45 for integer division.

Comment: @EmbSysDev [integer literal will have the first type that it fits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), so don't need to worry. In a 16-bit int environment then 95052 will have whatever type fits it (in this case most probably long). For the latter answer, the multiplication will be done first, not the division, so the result is not 1

Comment: Yes , I need to use 0~2000,regret the confusion.Currently I am using float and getting right results.It is not a very fast application so the performance is good enough.I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes. Using long is still much faster than float, and consumes much less code space because you don't need to include a float library

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the largest `N` such that `MPa*1.45038*2^N < 2^32`
2. Calculate the constant value of `K = floor(1.45038*2^N)` once
3. Calculate the value of `psi = (MPa*K)>>N` for every value of `MPa`

---

Since `0 <= MPa <= 2000`, you must choose `N` such that `2000*1.45038*2^N < 2^32`:

- `2^N < 2^32/(2000*1.45038)`
- `N < log(2^32/(2000*1.45038))`
- `N < 20.497`
- `N = 20`

---

Therefore, `K = floor(1.45038*2^N) = floor(1.45038*2^20) = 1520833`.

So for every value of `MPa`, you can calculate `psi = (MPa*1520833)>>20`.

You'll need to make sure that `MPa` is `unsigned` (or cast it accordingly).

Using this method will allow you to avoid floating-point operations.

---

For better accuracy, you can use `round` instead of `floor`, giving you `K = 1520834`.

In this specific case it will work out fine, because `2000*1520834` is smaller than `2^32`.

But with a different maximum value of `MPa` or a different conversion scalar, it might not.

In any case, the difference in the outcome of `psi` for each value of `K` is neglectable.

---

BTW, if you don't mind the additional memory, then you can use a look-up table instead:

- Add a pre-calculated global variable `const unsigned short lut[2001] = {...}`
- For every value of `MPa`, calculate `psi = lut[MPa]` instead of `psi = (MPa*K)>>N`
- So instead of `mul` + `shift` operations, your program will perform a `load` operation

Please note, however, that whether or not this is more efficient in terms of runtime performance depends on several things, such as the accessibility of the memory segment in which you allocate the look-up table, the architecture of the processor at hand, runtime caching heuristics, etc.

So you will need to apply some profiling on your program in order to decide which approach is better.